# How to resolve encoding error on loading files?

Tags: android, encode

I have encountered a problem in Android Studio. It seems like the error "File was loaded in the wrong encoding:'UTF-8'" persists in 90% of my java files.
I have made some upgrades: Gradle version -> 4.6 and Android plugin version -> 3.2.1

However, I don't think the upgrade is the problem. This thing occured after I clicked by mistake on Android Studio and then I forcely closed it while there were running proceses (gradle build, indexing, etc.).

I found 2 solutions on stack: #1 Tried to reload in another encoding (didn't work for any encoding type in the list); #2. Made another copy of the project (It worked but not for long; After another reload the encoding error appeared again).

This is an exemple of content from a java file.

�PNG

IHDR         �R9�   QIDATH�c�
$��)�e���@��F�b7�*�b1�Z�MEsQ������n.�hZ�2�F��Lף�q47�����8�Gs��͍ ���!
�D    IEND�B`�

Please tell me if I need to update the question with mode information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close your Android Studio, open your files with notepad++, save them and open again Android Studio.

Other solutions posted at Stack should work, but it seems that it is not working for some people.